# Slow Wi-Fi on Intel N 6235

Tags: wifi, intel

I have extremely slow Wi-Fi connection on my Linux Mint. The network controller is `Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)`. I found on the Ubuntu wiki a fix:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

I got:

```
Error: Module iwlwifi is in use by: iwldvm
```

So I did:

```
sudo rmmod iwldvm
sudo rmmod iwldvm # (went fine then)
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

My wlan0 was not up, so I started the iwldvm too.

```
sudo modprobe iwldvm
```

Unfortunately the Internet is still too slow. I tried different approaches but nothing worked. Mainly I am confused that the Wi-Fi worked fine for a week, now I am experiencing such troubles. I've read that the kernel upgrade to 3.10 should fix this, but I can't boot that one and 3.9 didn't fix this.

Is it possible that my machine (Asus Zenbook Prime) is using different thing then the `iwlwifi`? I am just asking because I found a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` called `iwlwifi.conf` which contains:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

The `lsmod | grep iwlwifi` command gives me:

```
iwlwifi               173477  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              510937  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
```

Comment: btw I can fix this changing the wireless mode to 802.11n, but otherwise it's slow...

Comment: I have the same laptop, running Ubuntu 12.04. Do you experience frequent loss of connectivity for about 30s at a time on certain 802.11n connections?

Comment: You mean being disconnect from wifi hotspot? No the connection is stable, but the speed is very various. If u meant something else, let me know how can i provide better info

Comment: No, Ubuntu reports that I'm still connected, but /var/log/kern.log reports every few minutes that it's reauthenticating and reassociating. During this time, connectivity is lost.

Answer (score 2):

My intel wifi would only connect at 54Mb/s(802.11g) speed.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

Also using iwlwifi driver

from syslog

```
  iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
```

What resolved it for me was to enable a setting on my wifi ap.

After enabling WMM/QoS on the router my ubuntu laptop connected with 802.11n(300 - 270Mb/s)

Answer (score 1):

I took the iwlwifi driver-6000g2b-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz from here http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi 
now everything works fast

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.